# Merging two small sequencies - algorithm

Tags: merge, proof, array-algorithms

Prove that it is enough to make at most 5 comparisons in order to merge two sorted sequences of lengths 2 and 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the input arrays are `[a b c d e]` and `[x y]`

We start by trying to insert `x` into the larger array. We do binary search but we take a chance: We don't start in the middle but slightly to the left: We check `x < b`.

- If we're *lucky* `x` falls in the left (smaller) part of the array and we can compare `x < a` to figure out if the result should start with `x a` or `a x`. We then have 3 comparisons left for `y` which is sufficient to do a binary search.
- If we're *unlucky* `x` falls in the right (larger) part of the array. In other words `x` should be in `c d e`. We continue the binary search by checking `x < d`.

  - If we're *lucky* this is false, because we then know that the result starts with `a b c d` and we can then check `x < e` and `y < e` to figure out the order of the last three elements.
  - If this is true, we check `x < c` to figure out if the sequence should start with `a b c x` or `a b x`. We then have 2 comparisons left which is enough to do a binary search for `y` since we know that it should be to the right of `x`.

This is of course just an outline of a solution and not a formal proof. However, it can easily be transformed to a formal proof using Hoare logic. It would look as follows:

```
{ a ≤ b ≤ c ≤ d ≤ e ∧ x ≤ y }
if (x < b) {
    { a ≤ b ≤ c ≤ d ≤ e ∧ x ≤ y ∧ x < b }
    if (x < a) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
} else {
    { a ≤ b ≤ c ≤ d ≤ e ∧ x ≤ y ∧ b ≤ x }
    if (x < d) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. A friend of mine (a PhD student from Argentina) has come up with exactly the same solution.

Comment: You're welcome. Say high to him from a fellow (former) PhD student from Sweden ;-)

Comment: Offtop: This is a BSc-level real examination task from a v. good university in my country. I wonder how they manage to solve 5 tasks like this in 90 min.

Comment: Heh. To be honest I don't think it very suitable for an exam. I hate exams with riddle / puzzle like questions.